# DataFrame sql - Spark scala order by is NOT giving right order

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a simple dataset and I'm trying to order the elements based on the "firstname" column. I used orderby and sort in scala, but it is giving some weird output.

```
    scala> val baseData = data.select($"Account.Number".as("AccountNumber"),
 $"Account.FirstName".as("FirstName"),
 $"Account.LastName".as("LastName"))

    baseData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = 
             [AccountNumber: string, FirstName: string ... 1 more field]

    scala>  baseData.show(false)
    +-------------+---------+--------+
    |AccountNumber|FirstName|LastName|
    +-------------+---------+--------+
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |456-DEF-456  |Sally    |Fuller  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |987-CBA-321  |Justin   |Pihony  |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |456-DEF-456  |Sally    |Fuller  |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |456-DEF-456  |Sally    |Fuller  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |987-CBA-321  |Justin   |Pihony  |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |456-DEF-456  |Sally    |Fuller  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |456-DEF-456  |Sally    |Fuller  |
    |987-CBA-321  |Justin   |Pihony  |
    |456-DEF-456  |Sally    |Fuller  |
    |456-DEF-456  |Sally    |Fuller  |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    +-------------+---------+--------+
    only showing top 20 rows


    scala> baseData.sort($"FirstName").show(false)
    +-------------+---------+--------+
    |AccountNumber|FirstName|LastName|
    +-------------+---------+--------+
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |333-XYZ-999  |Brad     |Turner  |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    |123-ABC-789  |Jay      |Smith   |
    +-------------+---------+--------+
    only showing top 20 rows
```

I'm getting some repeating rows. I tried with sort and orderby, but both result in repeated rows.

Comment: you sorted with first name it was sorted alphabetically. what is your problem ? if you want to see all the data in sorted order use `show('numOfRecordsYouWantToSee')`

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram .. see the output.. it is not sorted properly. it is showing ONLY brad and Jay only .. other names are NOT displaying

Comment: You have more than 20 rows in the dataframe, with a lot of repeated row, notice the part with `only showing top 20 rows`. When you sort the data all reapeated rows will be next to each other resulting in only two persons shown in the top 20 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate repeated rows, give `.dropDuplicates` at the end of the code, which will display distinct records.

```
baseData.sort($"FirstName").dropDuplicates.show(false)
```

To show all the elements inside the dataframe dynamically, use the overloaded method of `show` method by passing the dataframe count as the 1st parameter.

```
baseData.sort($"FirstName").dropDuplicates.show(baseData.count().toInt,false)
```